# How to Display 2D char Array on UIView. iOS

Tags: uiview, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D char Array, needed to display on a View.
for example I have array as-

```
char charArray[4][10] = {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',
                         ' ',' ',' ', A,m,i,t ,' ', ' ',' ',
                         ' ',' ',' ', K,u,m,a,r, ' ',' ', 
                         9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0
                        }
```

I want to display this content of array on UIView(not on TextView) on some action like button clicked.
And also want add some observer that reload UIView when any element of charArray changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIView doesn't provide any methods for rendering text. You should use an UI object that is made for this purpose like UITextView or UILabel.

The alternative would be to draw the text within a CGContext: `CGContextShowTextAtPoint()`

And since you are using a char-array and not an object you won't be able to implement an observer. You should consider creating your own class for that.